# 0x0000276B Error with c# PeerToPeer?

Tags: c#, networking

I tried to make a peer to peer system, but this error keeps popping up whenever i try to start the server. 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): WSAStartup cannot function at this time because the underlying system it uses to provide network services is currently unavailable.
Here is my code for the peerName:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.PeerToPeer;

namespace peer_name
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //foreach (Cloud ce in c)
            //    Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}", ce.Name);

            Console.Write("Enter PeerName classifier : ");
            string classifier = Console.ReadLine();
            //create a name for the p2p
            PeerName peerName = new PeerName(classifier, PeerNameType.Unsecured);
            //register in all the available clouds
            using (PeerNameRegistration registration = new PeerNameRegistration(peerName, 8080))
            {
                //get the creation time of the cloud 
                string timestamp = string.Format("Registration created at : {0}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
                registration.Comment = timestamp; //there is a limit for the comment
                //attack some datat to the registration 
                //registration.Data = new byte[5]; //limited to some amount
                //send the timestamp through the network
                UnicodeEncoding encoder = new UnicodeEncoding();
                byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(timestamp);
                registration.Data = data;

                //register everything
                try
                {
                    registration.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("HostName : {0}", registration.PeerName.PeerHostName);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    registration.Stop();
                }
                catch(PeerToPeerException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                //update the data by
                //registration.Update();


            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only have one connection with the same source IP. destination IP, and port number. So you may already have an existing connection with same 3 items.  From cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give a list of existing connections.  Make sure the connection doesn't exist.  Also make sure the server is started before you run app.  Error indicates you are make a network connection,  Your app is a client and needs the server start before app can run.  Netstat will indicate the server is Listening which will tell if server has been started.

Comment: i don't get what you mean by starting the server before i run the app because i get the error when i do the registration.Start()?

Comment: WSAStart() failing is a pretty serious mishap that you can't get help with here.  Reboot the machine, disable anti-malware, try the code on another machine, reformat the hard disk.

Comment: It looks like the PeerName is the server and uses port 8080.   The port number may already being used by another app so use Netstat to see if port 8080 is already being used.  The port 8080 may be blocked by firewall or virus checker.  Try a different port number like 9001 to see if you get same error.  To start the service you may need admin rights.  Not sure.

Comment: yeap it turned out that avast was stopping it from running. Thanks